# Actual time on netflix apple tv

Tags: appletv, netflix

When pausing Netflix on my apple TV it usually shows how far into the show I am, and at the right side of the bar will be how many minutes until the end of the show. Today, however, for maybe 10 seconds it was showing me the current time (10:49pm) and at the right side was when the show would finish (11pm). It then changed back to its usual display. I am wondering how to get it to show the clock time (e.g. 11pm) all the time

Answer (score 1):

You can see the time by tapping (not clicking) a second time after the elapsed time becomes visible.

You cannot switch this to appear permanently or by default.